# sql limiting number of rows based on column value

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL. I want to limit the students selected based on a specific table's cell value.

eg. following works

```
SELECT st.sid, st.sname, st.marks 
FROM student st, subjectcombinations sc 
WHERE st.scode = sc.scode 
LIMIT 10
```

But instead of hard coded 10 for limit, how can i use something like below

```
SELECT st.sid, st.sname, st.marks 
FROM student st, subjectcombinations sc 
WHERE st.scode = sc.scode 
LIMIT (SELECT intakecapacity FROM subjectcombinations);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT st.sid, st.sname, st.marks, @row := @row + 1
FROM student st, subjectcombinations sc, (select @row := 0) a
WHERE st.scode = sc.scode 
AND @row <= (SELECT intakecapacity FROM subjectcombinations);
```

Here's an example **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6104d3/5/0)**.

Please note that you need to use `ORDER BY`, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` would be pretty much pointless.